# ABC PDF anti-aliasing images when asked not to

Tags: c#, abcpdf

Adding a QR code as a bitmap to an ABCPDF document:

```
Doc pdf = new Doc();
pdf.Rendering.AntiAliasImages = false;
...
pdf.AddImageBitmap(bmp, true);
```

When rendered to a PDF file the image appears anti-aliased:

[image]

When printed direct to a printer the same the QR code is fine:

[image]

My question is: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like it's getting resized. I don't have much experience with AbcPDF doing direct build of a PDF like that (I render HTML into reports with it), but you might look at trying to keep it from getting resized.

Answer (score 1):

You need to size Doc.Rect based on the image size and resolution e.g.

```
// Set PDF image size from image size and resolution (PDF coord space is 72dpi)
doc.Rect.Height = bmp.Height * 72 / bmp.VerticalResolution;
doc.Rect.Width = bmp.Width * 72 / bmp.HorizontalResolution;
doc.AddImageBitmap(bmp, true);
```

(And the [Rendering](https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/xrendering/default.htm) class properties only apply when exporting from a PDF to an image.)